# How can I grab the nth record from a hive result?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I'm trying to grab a certain span of records from a hive result but am unable to find the clause to do this. Specifically I'd like to return records 200,000 to 400,000 from query result of several million records.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Rank() OVER(PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col2) as row_index  to index your rows and you can use the new column in where clause to get your desired result..

Note: It takes more time since system needs to order and give index